# Quality question based on bug stats

Tags: discussion

I've gathered some bug tracker stats for Qt, and since I don't have extensive experience with other development frameworks, I'd like to get some input on what to make out of those numbers from programmers with more experience.

Would programmers be the right place to ask, if not, where?

Comment: What is your core problem?  Keep in mind that this is a Q&A site so you have to have some kind of problem or answerable question, and this goes for StackOverflow as well.  This isn't a forum to "just get some thoughts".

Comment: My initial impression is that somehow these metrics you wish to use for debugging some C++ code with Qt.  If this is the case then this is not an appropriate site for the question.  Programmers is more for design questions and software engineering questions outside of coding issues.

Comment: The problem is that I personally find the stats alarming and not really a source of confidence for its future, and since I lack experience with other frameworks, I'd like an answer whether this amount of bugs and the proportion of open to fixed bugs and open to implemented community requests is normal, or north or south of it.

Comment: Can you write your question here? Questions about quality metrics are on-topic here, but I can't tell if your specific question is going to be a good fit or not. If you can edit your full proposed question into this one, I know that I'd have a better idea of if it would work here or not, or how to improve it.

Comment: @ThomasOwens - I'll see into it when I find some time to formulate it.

Comment: @ddriver Thanks. Feel free to ping me after you edit this question so I can get a notification and take a look.

Answer (score 2):

> The problem is that I personally find the stats alarming

That gives me the impression your question could easily be read as a rant against Qt. If that is true, this question will not be appropriate for Programmers. Moreover, questions specifically related to one tool are always on the edge of getting closed as either a request for tool recommendations, or a question which actually belongs on Stackoverflow, not Programmers.

However, if you manage it to write a general question on how to read bug tracker stats for certain kind of programs or software, and you manage it to make it a question which can be really answered based on facts, not just personal opinions, then it could be on-topic here.

My recommendation: if you have a question concerning Qt bug tracker stats, ask in their [Forums](https://forum.qt.io/) first (you can ask here [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21/the-whiteboard), too, but I guess people there will send you to the Forum, too).

Comment: Well, it is kind of hard to take it as a good thing really - about 15k open bugs, 5.7k P2, over 600 P1 - critical against 115 resolved bugs, 10k suggestions/feature requests against 15 implemented. Perhaps what's most alarming - as the numbers suggest, the amount of bugs is growing steadily. I was tempted to ask in their forums, but regulars there seem to be living in an alternate reality - whatever it is, Qt is awesome, the best thing ever. I am still processing how can I possibly put it in a way that doesn't look terrible.

Comment: Qt's forum is IMHO the only appropriate place to ask such a question. However, any *good* software has about one bug per 500-1000 lines of code. And for a software with 8 Mio lines of code, 15k seems not to be unreasonable (though it is IMHO unusual there are so many *known* bugs). The only thing which matters is: when you use Qt, how many of those bugs will really pop up to the end user of your application? And that might not have much to do with the sheer numbers you told us here.

Comment: "good software has about one bug per 500-1000 lines of code" - that doesn't sound like good software to me, but if that's the standard, it would explain a lot... there is also the "functionality per LOC" metric, where Qt doesn't impress either. But yeah, it is, in a way "the best" and "onliest" tool in its category, which is why I am using it, but I never got the "if you use it you must act like it is great" thing.

Comment: *"that doesn't sound like good software to me"* - and that is exactly your misconception. Looking for some references, I found [this SO post from 2011](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/625344/how-many-bugs-is-too-many), the second answer might be of interest to you.

Comment: I am still skeptical, making it sound like a universal law which it isn't really makes it sound like a dogma. But the amount of effort people invest varies quite a lot. Before getting into programming I was a graphics and video designer. I've been putting more attention and effort into fixing "single pixel" flaws than doctors put into saving lives. It may also explain my ability to find bugs and design limitations, couple of weeks back I found 5 different Qt bugs in a single day.  I will have to wait until my product is released to see how many bugs per LOC I the non-good programmer will have.